# Python logger not printing debug messages, despite explicit handler

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a logger in on of my files which has a handler attached to it and it's level has been set to debug. Despite that, when running my program, the debug statement is not printed to the console. The root logger is still set to warning, but I understood that if I add a handler to the logger, the log is passed to that handler and logged before being passed to the parent loggers (which is eventually a null logger). It doesn't seem that is the case. For context here is the code in the file:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(console_handler)


class OpenBST:
    app_data_folder = Path(user_data_dir(appname=lib_info.lib_name,
                                         appauthor="HydrOffice"))

    def __init__(self,
                 progress: CliProgress = CliProgress(use_logger=True),
                 app_data_path: Path = app_data_folder) -> None:
        app_data_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

        self.progress = progress

        self._prj = None
        self._app_info = OpenBSTInfo(app_data_path=app_data_path)
        self.current_project = None
        logging.debug("App instance started")
```

And below is where it's called in an example script:

```
from pathlib import Path

from hyo2.openbst.lib.openbst import OpenBST

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

project_directory = Path(os.path.expanduser("~/Documents/openbst_projects"))
project_name = "test_project"

# Create App instance
obst = OpenBST()
```

Why doesn't the `logger.debug('App instance started')` not print out to the console?

EDIT:
The code below includes the suggestion from @Jesse R
`__init__` was modified as such:

```
class OpenBST:
    app_data_folder = Path(user_data_dir(appname=lib_info.lib_name,
                                         appauthor="HydrOffice"))

    def __init__(self,
                 progress: CliProgress = CliProgress(use_logger=True),
                 app_data_path: Path = app_data_folder) -> None:
        app_data_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(console_handler)

        self.progress = progress

        self._prj = None
        self._app_info = OpenBSTInfo(app_data_path=app_data_path)
        self.current_project = None
        logger.debug("App instance started")
```

No output is generated (exit code 0).
My understanding was a handler attached to a logger would execute before passing log up the chain (where the root is still set to warning).

Comment: Could it be a typo in your code, `logging` vs `logger`,  when you call `debug`?

Comment: That's was definitely a typo. and fixed now, thanks. But the issue is still the same, it's likely an inheritance issue as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

You call `logging.debug("App instance started")`, which is not part of the logger that you declare from `getLogger`. You can set the debug level universally for `logging` with

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

also calling `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` outside of the class does not inherit correctly, since you're not passing it but instead use `logging`. You can create a new logger by moving that declaration inside of the class.

For Example:

```
import logging


class SampleClass:

    def __init__(self):
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.info('will log')

logging.info('will not log')
SampleClass()
```

Running:

```
$ python logtest.py 
INFO:__main__:will log
```

Comment: You're right in the first part that I had a typo. The second part though, adding the logger in the class seems contrary to the module level logger best practice mentioned in the docs. 
Still, switching the logger to be inside the sample class, I don't see the debug log get printed out. I think what is confusing me is that, despite having attached a handler to the logger, it's still not printing out. Which according to the flow diagram in the docks, it should.

Comment: Can I see an updated version of the code in `__init__`?

Comment: I have appended the code as an edit to the original question @Jesse R

Comment: call `setLevel` on the logger itself with `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` instead of the stream handler